# Open iTunes Store Review on iOS10.1

Tags: xcode8, ios10

I was using in my app this link to user review:

```
- (IBAction)rateMyApp:(id)sender {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/881623474"]];
```

the openURL is deprecated so now it is using according to the developer website this one:

```
- (IBAction)rateMyApp:(id)sender {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:<#(nonnull NSURL *)#> options:<#(nonnull NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)#> completionHandler:<#^(BOOL success)completion#>]];
```

But I can not make it work any help is more than welcome.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check in real iPhone/iPad? In simulator this not works. In device it works. If not works then make sure you return YES in openURL function in AppDelegate class.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application openURL:(NSURL*)url sourceApplication:(NSString*)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I am checking in a device, should I delete the IBAction and insert your line instead?

Comment: rateMyApp function is fine. See inside that you are opening UIApplication openURL. So goto your AppDelegate class and add above function that I mentioned in answer